# Thumbnails of leftMirrored photos are in the wrong orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I'm writing an app that used the front camera to take a picture. I'd like to mirror the pictures across the vertical axis, and then save them.

The problem is that when I look in the default Photos app, the thumbnails of the images are rotated 180 degrees. If I click on the picture its still in the rotated picture, but the instance I try zooming in, it corrects itself to my desired rotation with the mirror effect I want. Any ideas? This is happening in the official Apple Photos app.

My code for mirroring pictures is here:

```
var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
myImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: chosenImage.CGImage!, scale: chosenImage.scale, orientation: .LeftMirrored)
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImageView.image!, self, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the orientation doesn't actually change the image data. The orientation of the image needs to be manually saved/changed